# dnsmasq not working without internet connection in OS X Yosemite

Tags: localhost, osx-yosemite, dnsmasq

No0b here. I have been trying to setup a local environment for web development on OS X Yosemite using these approaches (http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/ and http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/)

The culprit here is **dnsmasq**. It is supposed to automatically update **/etc/hosts** with **folder-name.dev** everytime I create new sites. It works well only when connected to the internet. When I'm offline, Google Chrome returns `Unable to connect to the internet` everytime I tried to access any **.dev** that wasn't registered in /etc/hosts.

I have checked the status of dnsmasq using LaunchRocket and it's stated as running. Also, running `$ dig folder-name.dev @127.0.0.1` returns no error.

However, `$ ping folder-name.dev` returns `ping: cannot resolve folder-name.dev: Unknown host`. And when I run `$ scutil --dns` while offline, all I get is `No DNS configuration available`

Any idea how to get dnsmasq to run properly even without internet connection?

FYI, I am running clean install OS X 10.10 Yosemite on MacBook Pro 15" Late 2008.

Comment: Related: [Set DNS server on OS X even when without internet connection](http://serverfault.com/questions/22419/set-dns-server-on-os-x-even-when-without-internet-connection) on Server Fault (without a solution for Yosemite today).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's "bug" with Yosemite. Check out this posting, https://github.com/BrianGilbert/OSXAegirInstaller/issues/34:

> you could also try this.. https://github.com/joedj/yosemite_dnsfix (didn't appear to work for me though)
>
> [...]
>
> This has been escalated to Apple engineers by myself and I am awaiting a response, a workaround that I've confirmed works (but am not electing to use myself) is available at: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it
>
> [...]
>
> Response from applecare is that engineers said it's "Expected behaviour" no idea if they will ever fix it..

And from https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8969581:

> So the response from Apple is that is expected behavior, and the applecare contact suggested I use the hack proposed at http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-i... (which I sent to them)
>
> At this stage he doesn't know if it will ever get fixed.. no indication from engineering..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/157730) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way, should the linked page ever change or become invalid for any reason, the answer will still be useful to visitors to [su].

Comment: Ah yes, the good old Apple engineering "expected behavior". It's either that or "reinstall the OS".