# Mac Apache Server not working when wireless is turned off

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac, apache-http-server

I am having an issue where I setup my local apache server on my Mac OS X Yosemite. The server has been working great up until I needed to work remotely without wireless access. I have been looking all over for a solution to get the server to work when I am offline but cannot seem to yield results.

I have these settings in my .conf

```
Listen *:80
ServerName localhost
```

These in my hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

While offline I can ping 127.0.0.1 successfully but when I try and ping or traceroute to one of my vhosts domains I says host cannot be found.

```
traceroute example.dev
```

What settings can I look at in order to get this working offline? Do I need to setup a new network interface?

**Note:** 
I am not using XAMPP or MAMP. Just the pre-installed apache server on the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define `example.dev` anywhere, so how would your computer know it needs to map to your machine? I *assume* it is defined somewhere in your network though, and then maps to `127.0.0.1`.

(Likewise, domains such as `lvh.me` and `lvho.st`, aka Local Virtual Host, are registered by some people who made them and al their subdomains point to `127.0.0.1`.)

Note that `.dev` is [a proposed level domain](http://icannwiki.com/.dev). When pinging or digging it on my machine, I see:

```
dig example.dev

example.dev.        3600    IN  A   127.0.53.53
```

...where this special IP address [should ring alarm bells](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-2013-12-06-en#127.0.53.53):

> 127.0.53.53 is a special IPv4 address that will appear in system logs alerting system administrators that there is potential name collision issue, enabling a quick diagnosis and remediation. The "53" is used as a mnemonic to indicate a DNS-related problem owing to the use of network port 53 for the DNS service.

I don't know how it got mapped like that in my network; maybe as the `.dev` domain is in a proposal state and someone already partially added it? As an aside: *all* `.dev` domains map to that IP address for me. Still then, `127.0.53.53` does not map to my local web server.

So, I *assume* that `example.dev` maps to `127.0.0.1` in your network, and to make your computer lookup the name, it needs a network connection. As using `.dev` might clash if the proposed top level domain is ever assigned, and as you want things to work without a network connection, you could add other aliases to your host file. Like on the line for `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost my.host www.my.host subdomain2.my.host another-host
```

You can see where that is going if you need many (sub)domains... To use wildcards without a network connection, you'd probably need to set up some DNS server on your local machine.

To quickly see if all this is indeed the issue, just add `example.dev`:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost example.dev
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I added `127.0.0.1    localhost example.dev` to my hosts and that vhost started to work. So I have dnsmasq setup to map all `.dev` domains. Which was dynamically routing as I understand. And with that I didn't need to add a hosts entry while online.

Comment: @brenjt, are you saying you set up dnsmasq just now as a fix, or did you already use that and was *that* giving you problems? If you set it up now: what did you do to make dnsmasq work when not connected? (My dnsmasq installation does not actually work when I disconnect from my network, on Yosemite. I guess that is related to my `resolve-file` not being set in `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, hence using its default `/etc/resolve.conf` which does not exists when not connected. Still then Yosemite, should be able to find my `/etc/resolver/mydomain` files, which tell OS X to use dnsmasq...)

Comment: Ah, see [dnsmasq not working without internet connection in OS X Yosemite](http://superuser.com/questions/835631/dnsmasq-not-working-without-internet-connection-in-os-x-yosemite) (no solution yet), @brenjt.

Comment: Ah, well I guess I'll stick to manually adding the entries to my hosts file until Apple officially addresses the issue,